# How to successfully convert JSON data to Objective-C objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, json

So the jist of what I'm doing is simple, getting some data from a server in JSON format. I'm using the default classes in Objective-C (specifically NSJSONSerialization) to convert the responseData gotten into JSON format.

So basically-

```
   NSString* testURL=@"http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getsimilar&artist=Kendrick+Lamar&track=A.D.H.D&api_key=e3f53f2f2896b44ff158a586b8ee15c7&format=json";

   NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:testURL]];

   NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

   NSArray* songList = [json objectForKey:@"similartracks"];
```

Problem is, later when I try to access an indivdual object in the array of JSOn data, like so,

```
   NSDictionary* song1 = [songList objectAtIndex:0];
```

It's giving me this error,

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x96e2b60'

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

I appreciate the help,
coffeejay

Comment: One simple thing to do is to NSLog your `json` variable right after you create it.  NSLog will print out a representation that fairly well resembles the original JSON (though with `()` chars instead of `{}`, if I'm remembering correctly), so you can see what you have.  Then again NSLog after each step of "peeling" the data.  (Of course, you'd remove the NSLogs in your final code, and add `isKindOfClass` checks.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `[json objectForKey:@"similartracks"]` returns a NSDictionary, try something like this: 
`NSArray* songList = [[json objectForKey:@"similartracks"] objectForKey:@"track"]`

Comment: This is a bad approach, which will likely lead to more crashes. How do you know that key "similartracks" contains an `NSDictionary` instance? Add sanity checks.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with such things, you should always validate your response before trying to do something with it, you should never trust any input. In your case, you're trying to send `objectAtIndex:` message to an `NSDictionary` instance, which raises unrecognised selector exception.

A simple way to avoid such crashes is to check the class of the returned object, for instance:

```
id song1 = json[@"similartracks"]
if([song1 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    //Now we're sure it's an array
}
```

Comment: Checking to make sure what you got back is good programming style.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the returned data to be `data`, but you are passing `NSJSONSerialization` method a variable called `responseData`.

Answer (score 0):

Your json probably doesn't return an array at yhat point but a dictionary. Show the json content so we can help further.

(NsJSonSerialization returns id and can be either an array or dictionary. The contents again will be arrays or dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says that songList is a dictionary and not an array. Check the data structure.